# How to display .png format image from ajax response?

Tags: ajax

I am sending ajax response.getOutputStream().write(encoder.pngEncode()) image in bytes,
i want to display image at runtime in my jsp from the ajax response is it possible?
Can u please anyone can solve this issue.

In Servlet class:

```
chartImage = chart.createBufferedImage(400, 300);       
        PngEncoder encoder = new PngEncoder(chartImage, false, 0, 9);

        resp.setContentType("image/png"); 
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        resp.getOutputStream().write(encoder.pngEncode());
```

---

In JSP:

```
if (bbyHttpRequest.readyState == 4) 
    { 
        if(bbyHttpRequest.status == 200) 
        { 
        alert("inside ajax call");

        var respone=bbyHttpRequest.responseText;

        alert("respone----------->"+respone);

        //var i = new Image();
        //i.src = respone;

           //document.getElementById("imgChart1").innerHTML = '<%=request.getContextPath() + "/CreateOMSMonitorScreenTest" %>';
          // document.getElementById("imgChart1").value = '<%=request.getContextPath() + "/CreateOMSMonitorScreenTest" %>';
          document.getElementById("imgChart1").value=respone;

        } 
        else 
        {
        alert(' Dynamic call to web server failed.Please refresh the page. ');
        } 
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. AJAX is causing the problem, not solving it. Don't overuse it!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a server that returns PNG images, you don't have to use ajax, you can use simple HTML:

```
<img src='myServer.thing?param=value' alt='Loading Failed' />
```

You can use JavaScript to handle errors of the `img` tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are [data urls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), so you can create a tag like <img src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgo..." />

However, IE6 does not support that, which might or might not be an issue for you.